# Pythagoras tree in Java: How do I calculate the third point of the triangle?

Tags: java, tree, point, pythagorean

Dear more advanced programmers,
I have to programm a Pythagoras tree (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_tree_(fractal) ) and I want to take a step forward, but I just can't.

I want to create the 3rd point of the triangle, but after 2 days of searching in books, internet, my head, etc., I just did not find a solution. Well, I have a solution, but it wont work for the recursive step and I don't know how to create the 3rd and 4th point of the following squares.

I want my programm to draw the step 1 of the tree.

Here's my code for the calculation so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double ax;
    double ay;
    double bx;
    double by;
    double cx;
    double cy;
    double dx;
    double dy;
    ax = 0.25;
    ay = 0.75;
    bx = 0.25;
    by = 0.25;
    cx = 0.75;
    cy = 0.25;
    dx = 0.75;
    dy = 0.75;

    StdDraw.line(ax,ay,bx,by); // ax etc. are doubles
    StdDraw.line(bx,by,cx,cy);
    StdDraw.line(cx,cy,dx,dy);
    StdDraw.line(dx,dy,ax,ay);  
    double alpha;
    double beta;
    double random = 0.0;
    while(random <= 0.3 || random >= 0.6){  //random angular between 30&60
        random = Math.random();
    }
        random = random*100; //to make it an angular
        alpha = random;      //set alpha to this angular
        beta = 90-alpha;
        double sinusBeta= Math.toRadians(beta);
        double sinusAlpha= Math.toRadians(alpha);
        sinusBeta = Math.sin(sinusBeta);
        sinusAlpha = Math.sin(sinusAlpha);
        double side_b = 0.5*sinusBeta;
            double side_a = 0.5*sinusAlpha;
            double hypothenuse = Math.sqrt((side_b*side_b)+(side_a*side_a));
            double p = (side_a*side_a)/hypothenuse;  //to get h of the triangle
            double q= (side_b*side_b)/hypothenuse;
            double h = Math.sqrt(p*q);
            double triangleTop_x = ax+q; 
            double triangleTop_y = ay+h;

        StdDraw.line(ax, ay, triangleTop_x , triangleTop_y);
        StdDraw.line(dx, dy, triangleTop_x , triangleTop_y);
}
```

I know that this is not the right way to get the last triangle point cause it has the condition that the hypothenuse is exactly in the direction of the x-axis. Which is not true for step two anymore, so a recursive method would not behave as it should. I wrote all the code by my own, I know it is not the best one, but it would be awesome to get an idea of how I can build the triangle and the following squares not direction-dependent.
Thank you so much in advance for any ideas that may help!

Comment: Oh, I see the triangle.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work for the next steps as it does for the first: The clue of the Pythagoras tree is the recursion. :(

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this is more a question about geometry in the coordinate system than about Java programming?

Comment: I’m a bit rusty here, but I think you want to use a vector and multiply it by some matrix, where the matrix is constant for the entire tree (as long as the angle `alpha` is constant). You may want to search the net for such stuff.

Comment: Thank you! It's kind of both, cause I know how I build this with geometry, but it is not the "right" geometry for Java, obviously. I know how I do this on a piece of paper (that's what the code is so far), but java can't work with it. So it is more the question: what kind of geometry should I use that Java can use it? That is why I asked here.
Sadly alpha is not constant because with every step of recursion it will be another, caused by math.random (definition of task by my university). I will try the matrix-thing!